# Why when I'm setting parent div to hide ( via jQuery ) flash player which is in this div stops playing?

Tags: flash, mozilla

I hava Youtube player in my DIV element. When I'm using this method:
`$("#mydivb").hide();` Youtube player stops playing. This is observed only in **Mozilla Firefox**, IE and Chrome are working just fine ( keeps playing when parent div hidden).

I don't see how js script can't affect flash player. Any ideas?

Comment: 1st, this has nothing to do with flash.

Comment: Ok, what is it connected with. I have new instalation of firefox, no adBlock...